# Broken ghostscript configuration

Tags: 16.04, ghostscript

Something has gone awry with my ghostscript configuration, whereby I get the following errors when, for example, using epstopdf

---

```
 ./base/gsicc_manage.c:1088: gsicc_open_search(): Could not find default_gray.icc 
| ./base/gsicc_manage.c:1914: gsicc_init_iccmanager(): cannot find default icc profile
  ./base/gsicc_manage.c:1088: gsicc_open_search(): Could not find default_rgb.icc 
| ./base/gsicc_manage.c:1708: gsicc_set_device_profile(): cannot find device profile

**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.
  ./base/gsicc_manage.c:1088: gsicc_open_search(): Could not find default_gray.icc 
| ./base/gsicc_manage.c:1708: gsicc_set_device_profile(): cannot find device profile
Unrecoverable error: unknownerror in .special_op
  ./base/gsicc_manage.c:1088: gsicc_open_search(): Could not find default_gray.icc 
+ ./base/gsicc_manage.c:2650: gs_setdefaultgrayicc(): cannot find default gray icc profile
```

---

I figured out the following workaround (inserted in my .bashrc)

```
alias gs='gs -sICCProfilesDir=/usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript/'<br>
alias epstopdf='epstopdf --gsopt=-sICCProfilesDir=/usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript/' <br>
alias ps2pdf='ps2pdf -sICCProfilesDir=/usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript/'
```

However, I couldn't find a way of making this setting 'global'. E.g. when say epstopdf is called from export_fig matlab it gives similar errors to above, unless I implement a similar workaround.

I think this has had knock-on effects of stopping printing from working properly on my system.

```
Ubuntu 16.04  
ghostscript, Version: 9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.6
```

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: Complete SWAG - but have you tried re-installing the `libgs9-common` package?

Comment: I did this with `sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends libgs9-common` ... `sudo apt-get install  libgs9-common`. Hmm it apears to have fixed `epstopdf` but stopped the workaround functioning for `gs`. Should I go ahead and purge libgs9-common fully (uninstalling dependencies) then reinstall all the packages?

Comment: I don't know . . . I would have tried `sudo apt install --reinstall libgs9-common` rather than the lower-level `dpkg`, but I don't know if the outcome would be different. Do you know where the `/usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript/` files come from? I can't find a package that provides them (the default color profiles appear to live in `/usr/share/ghostscript/9.18/iccprofiles/`)

Comment: Reinstalling via apt was the same. The workaround needed updating to `/usr/share/ghostscript/9.18/iccprofiles/` as you say. Any other culprit things to try reinstalling?

Comment: Please run `gs --help` and copy the list of `Search path`s into your question.  Are any relevant environment variables defined (`env | grep GS_`)?

Comment: By default no icc-file-containing location shows up in the search path list for `gs --help`. By adding `export GS_LIB=/usr/share/ghostscript/9.18/iccprofiles/` to .bashrc it does appear with `gs --help`, as expected. However, bizarrely the error persists exactly as before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60438/discussion-between-james-and-steeldriver).

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find a way to fix it?

Answer (score 22):

Here's what worked for me:

```
sudo rmdir /usr/share/ghostscript/9.25/iccprofiles
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgs9-common
```

Something had left an empty directory at `/usr/share/ghostscript/9.25/iccprofiles`.  It appears that `libgs9-common` creates a symlink from `/usr/share/ghostscript/9.25/iccprofiles` to `/usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript`, but silently fails to create it if there's already something in the filesystem.

Comment: Worked for me too, in 18.04.

Comment: Amazing. I had printing completely broken on Ubuntu 18.04 and then on 18.10, then I realized Evince couldn't open PS files. Your solution works perfectly.

Comment: Ville, worked for me too! Thank you very much indeed! Was having problems with cups-pdf not printing into ~/PDF; turned out gs was failing with code 255 (thanks Volker for pointing that out) and to you for your recipe as it finally brought gs back from a broken state.