# printers not working after distribution upgrade

Tags: 18.04, printing

After upgrading distribution from 16.04 to 18.04.1, both printers I have (Epson L805 and HP 7500A) have stopped working. Cups Log file for epson 
test page show:

```
./base/gsicc_manage.c:1244: gsicc_open_search(): Could not find default_gray.icc 
./base/gsicc_manage.c:2025: gsicc_set_device_profile(): cannot find device profile
Unrecoverable error: rangecheck in .putdeviceprops
Operand stack:
[Job 2256] true
[Job 2256] PID 21466 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster) stopped with status 1.
[Job 2256] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
[Job 2256] PID 21467 (/opt/epson-inkjet-printer-escpr/cups/lib/filter/epson-escpr-wrapper) stopped with status 1.
[Job 2256] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
[Job 2256] Can\'t open CUPS raster file.
[Job 2256] PID 21469 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/lpd) exited with no errors.
[Job 2256] End of messages
[Job 2256] printer-state=3(idle)
[Job 2256] printer-state-message="Filter failed"
[Job 2256] printer-state-reasons=none
```

Using 64 bit epson driver for L805 printer (epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.30-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb driver) and lsb-9.2

I tried all of the following, with no success:

1. Clear var/spool/cups.
2. Uninstall and re-install printers and drivers.
3. Use old driver from Epson, epson-inkjet-printer-l805_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb.
4. Removed hplip v. 3.17.10 and installed hplip version 3.18.9 (latest)
5. upgraded printer firmware to latest version.
6. connected and installed as usb printer.
7. tried previous epson driver (1.6.17-2). This has added the missing file epson-escpr-wrapper in usr/lib/cups/filter directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printer “Filter failed”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080720/printer-filter-failed). (To be voted after the bounty finishes.) @bob Please don’t put the solution into the question. If it’s just a link, post a comment, otherwise create an answer.

Comment: Finally, solution is described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080720/printer-filter-failed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printer "Filter failed"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080720/printer-filter-failed)

Answer (score 2):

From [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1080926/307523) which author will hopefully post here:

I encountered the same problem. To track back its origin I looked into 
"/var/log/cups/error_log" 
In my case, I discovered that the problem was caused by icc profiles used by ghostscript. I had the following error:

> Started filter pstops (PID 26489)
>   ./base/gsicc_manage.c:1244: gsicc_open_search(): Could not find default_gray.icc
>   ./base/gsicc_manage.c:2261: gsicc_init_iccmanager(): cannot find default icc profile
>   ./base/gsicc_manage.c:1244: gsicc_open_search(): Could not find default_rgb.icc
>   ./base/gsicc_manage.c:2025: gsicc_set_device_profile(): cannot find device profile
>   **** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.

So what worked out for me has been to manually remove the icc profiles and then re-install libgs9-common (following [Broken ghostscript configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924915/broken-ghostscript-configuration)) :

> sudo rmdir /usr/share/ghostscript/9.25/iccprofiles
>   sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgs9-common

Hope this helps

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of the linked answer that had been already known by OP. What are you going to achieve by reposting it here?

Comment: Questions should have answers. Hopefully the author posts the answer which I requested.