# Canon MG 3500 series printer 'filter failed'

Tags: 18.04, printing, canon

I have recently upgraded to 18.04. Prior to this my printer worked fine without any system changes. After the upgrade I get the 'filter failed' message whenever I try to print doc's, test page, etc. I have tried a few things already posted. I have un-installed and re-installed several times. I have re-intalled a similar printer.

The last thing I tried was to install the 'driver' `cnijfilter-mg3500series-4.00-1-deb.tar.gz` from the Canon Asia site. I installed the deb package and still get filter failed.

The Error message in /var/log/cups/error_log is;

```
E [14/Oct/2018:00:10:01 +1100] Unknown directive BrowseAddress on line 26 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
E [14/Oct/2018:11:06:41 +1100] Unknown directive BrowseAddress on line 26 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
E [14/Oct/2018:11:07:01 +1100] Unknown directive BrowseAddress on line 26 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
E [14/Oct/2018:11:07:31 +1100] [Job 35] Job stopped due to filter errors; please consult the error_log file for details.
```

Line 26 of my `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` file is;

```
BrowseAddress @LOCAL
```

I have spent a lot of time sifting through the net with no solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Canon Pixma MG7550.
I found the solution here:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1083318

Steps to follow:

```
sudo rm -r /usr/share/ghostscript/9.25/iccprofiles
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgs9-common
```