# Upgrade Ubuntu 16.06 LTS -> 18.04, Printer Brother HL-L2320D Stopped working

Tags: drivers, upgrade, 18.04, printing

I recently upgraded ubuntu to 18.04 from 16.04 and my usb connected printer make and model Brother HL-L2320D is no longer working. I've removed the printer from within settings and then reinstalled my drivers from:
https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hll2320d_us_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625
I see that during a test print, the light on my printer sparkles, i.e. like its comunicating, but the print job doesn't come out. My printer status is empty (as opposed to originally I had some "filter failed" status).

Any help would be greatly appreciated

---

Found the Solution! This explains the problem and the solution

[Broken ghostscript configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924915/broken-ghostscript-configuration)

Answer (score 1):

Again just to be clear, the upgrade cleaned out some files referred to in this other post. I therefore wasn't able to print with ANY printer, even though it seemd my OS was comunicating with the printer (i.e. it saw it, and when print jobs were sent, the lights would blink, and Id recieve a Filter failed status). This happend with HP printer, Cannon, and my Brother.

Thanks to this post:

[Broken ghostscript configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924915/broken-ghostscript-configuration)