# HP Printer stopped working with 18.04 upgrade

Tags: drivers, 18.04, printing, hp

I'm a bit stumped. Upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. My HP Deskjet stopped working. It's an HP Deskjet F4280 All in One. I installed HPLIP 3.18.9 and everything looks alright with that. However, the printer still won't print. The printer is detected. I can also get the scanner to work. What I can't do is get it to print anything, even a test page. I checked the printer with an old Mac laptop and that prints fine so the problem lies in neither the cable nor the printer itself. Can anyone give me an pointers on trouble shooting this? Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

StackExchange works great! No sooner than I post my question, I find the diagnosis and solution.

This is not an issue with my printer or its drivers! This is an issue with broken Ghostscript dependencies. Several people have encountered this. If you're facing this problem, go check the following post: [Broken ghostscript configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924915/broken-ghostscript-configuration)

This has the diagnosis and the solution.